# How to find the similarity in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, dplyr, statistics

I have a data set as I've shown below:

It shows which book is sold by which shop.

```
df <- tribble(
 ~shop,  ~book_id,  
  "A",       1,      
  "B",       1,      
  "C",       2,      
  "D",       3,      
  "E",       3,      
  "A",       3,      
  "B",       4,      
  "C",       5,      
  "D",       1,      
)
```

In the data set,

- shop **A** sells 1, 3
- shop **B** sells 1, 4
- shop **C** sells 2, 5
- shop **D** sells 3, 1
- shop **E** sells only 3

So now, I want to calculate the Jaccard index here. For instance, let's take **shop A** and **shop B**. There are **three** different books that are sold by A and B (book 1, book 3, book 4). However, only **one** product is sold by both shops (this is product 1). So, the **Jaccard index** here should be **33.3% (1/3)**.

Here is the sample of the desired data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~shop_1, ~shop_2, ~similarity,  
    "A",    "B",         33.3,  
    "B",    "A",         33.33,
    "A",    "C",          0,
    "C",    "A",          0,
    "A",    "D",         100,
    "D",    "A",         100,
    "A",    "E",          50,
    "E",    "A",          50,

)
```

Any comments/assistance really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is about math and/or theory of how to do the comparison. For that, I suggest either [stats.se] or [datascience.se], but SO is not the place to ask how to do this. If you have problems with a function you already know, that's one thing, but not this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @r2evans. I thought someone might know an R package to do this comparison. That's why I wanted to write a post to get the suggestion. I'd be happy if you could leave it for a while.

Comment: Some questions (1) For the purposes of this question, does the distinction between ID and Type matter? E.g., if Shop A sells 1X and Shop B sells 1Y, should those be counted as somewhat similar, while an exact match (1X to 1X) would be more similar? Your text says "similarity among shops based on `book_id`", which suggests `type` is irrelevant for this question. If this is the case, I would suggest removing `type` from your sample data. (2) We need much more detail about "similarity" - what are you looking for in this measure. Some examples to think about...

Comment: I understand, but also please realize that StackOverflow explicitly tries to *not* be a recommendation engine, per its list of things that are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) including *"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial"*.

Comment: (a) How about the count of books sold in both shops? That is, indeed, a data manipulation problem. Would that do what you want? Why or why not? (b) Or maybe a percent overlap - what percentage of Shop A books does Shop B sell? (c) Does it need to be *symmetric*? - that is, one score per pair? If Shop A sells 5 books, and Shop B sells 50 books, including all of the books that A sells, do you want a single score for the similarity between A and B, or maybe A,B gets one score and B,A gets a different score?

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, I simply want to calculate the intersection. For instance, both A and B shops are selling 2 products, but only 1 product is common. So the intersection is %50. That's it.

Comment: @GregorThomas You absolutely got what I wanted to say. :)

Comment: @datazang then you should put that in your question! Your sentence *"I don't how to calculate the similarity"* makes it sound like you don't know what you want at all. But let me push you farther. Let's say Shop A sells book 1 and book 2, and Shop B sells book 2. What is the result you want? What is Shop B sells book 2 and book 3?

Comment: A couple of things worth considering would be jaccard index and Dice index,  each of which measure the similarity of sets like this.

Comment: @GregorThomas, For your example, the result should be 50%, because there are only two unique books that are sold by A and B (book 1 and book 2), and only book 2 is common.

Comment: It seems Jaccard Index would be the best option to do this as @G5W suggested.

Comment: @datazang I would suggest editing your question to (a) remove `type`, as it doesn't seem relevant, (b) clarify what you want in text, (c) clarify what you want from your sample data by filling in the question marks. (You may also want to adjust your sample data do be smaller, so this part is easier to do by hand). Then we can open it up and get you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a package but you can write your own function. I guess by similarity you mean something like this:

```
similarity <- function(x, y) {
  k <- length(intersect(x, y))
  n <- length(union(x, y))
  k / n
}
```

Then you can use `tidyr::crossing` to merge the same data frame with itself

```
dfg <- df %>% group_by(shop) %>% summarise(books = list(book_id))
crossing(dfg %>% set_names(paste0, "_A"), dfg %>% set_names(paste0, "_B")) %>% 
  filter(shop_A != shop_B) %>% 
  mutate(similarity = map2_dbl(books_A, books_B, similarity))
```